# How to add date and time to squid log?

Tags: linux, logging, squid

The standard squid log format writes time in seconds from epoch. How to add date and time in a human readable format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these to squid.config file:

```
logformat timereadable %tl %6tr %>a %Ss/%03Hs %<st %rm %ru %un %Sh/%<A %mt
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log timereadable
```

then restart squid:

```
systemctl restart squid //for debian
```

Make sure the path were file is to be written exists.

Comment: For ISO 8601 format **with** milliseconds replace `%tl` with `%{%FT%T}tl.%03tu%{%z}tl`. That is to say: most of the date in the first `%{<strftime formatting>}tl`, a zero-padded `%tu` for the milliseconds, followed by just the time zone from a second `%tl`. Not pretty but it works. See [Time related format codes](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/logformat/).